# RestKit Mapping a string array without key paths

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm having a problem mapping a JSON array of strings with no key paths using RestKit 0.20.3. My classes are based on the the example in the RestKit [wiki](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#mapping-values-without-key-paths).

JSON:

```
"feature_list":{
    "property":["test","test ","test","test"],
    "street":["test1","foo","bar"],
    "garden":["foo","bar"],
    "other":["foo","bar", "test2"]
}
```

Classes:

```
@interface FeatureList : NSManagedObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSSet *property;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSSet *street;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSSet *garden;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSSet *other;

@end

@interface Feature : NSManagedObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *featureType;

@end
```

Mapping Setup:

```
+ (RKMapping *)featureListMapping {
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"FeatureList" inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];
    [mapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"property" mapping:[self featureMapping]];
    [mapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"street" mapping:[self featureMapping]];
    [mapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"garden" mapping:[self featureMapping]];
    [mapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"other" mapping:[self featureMapping]];
}

+ (RKMapping *)featureMapping {
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Feature" inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];
    [mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"featureType"]];
    return mapping;
}
```

When debugging the feature.featureType object in Xcode, a RKMappingSourceObject object is returned with the value stored in an object property, which I can't access.
When printing feature.featureType.class, NSCFString is printed.

```
for (Feature * feature in featureList.property)
{
    //feature.featureType is a RKMappingSourceObject in the debugger
   NSString *featureStr = feature.featureType.class;  //prints NSCFString
}
```

Log output:

```
Mapped attribute value from keyPath '(null)' to 'featureType'. Value: test ({
    HTTP =     {
        request =         {
            URL = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/test";
            headers =             {
            };
            method = GET;
        };
        response =         {
            URL = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/test";
            headers =             {
                "Cache-Control" = "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate";
                "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                Etag = "\"193d0f470155872e5b36e9f7586c0c8f\"";
                "Proxy-Connection" = Close;
                Server = "thin 1.5.0 codename Knife";
                "X-Request-Id" = 0e4de78e656ef2165699385695cdfe75;
                "X-Runtime" = "0.092788";
                "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge";
            };
        };
    };
    mapping =     {
        collectionIndex = 1;
        rootKeyPath = response;
    };
})
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Not clear what your problem is. Everything looks correct. Where / when are you debugging? What is failing to work for you?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not being clearer, the problem is that I'm unable to get the feature.featureType value as an NSString, it is returning as a NSCFString instead.

Comment: `NSCFString` is a type of `NSString` (it's a class cluster)...

Comment: How can I extract the string value from the NSCFString? The NSCFString description is printed as: test ({HTTP ={request ={URL = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/test";headers ={};method = GET;};

Comment: When are you printing it out? Is should only give that log during the mapping process because a proxy object is used. Once the mapping is complete you should just have the string ('test' in this case).

Comment: I'm printing it out in a UIViewController. It doesn't look like it's converting to a NSString successfully, this is a screenshot of feature.featureType in debug mode: http://i.imgur.com/cn2Dzqc.png

Comment: I get that, but when? What line of code are you debugging? Check in the success block using the mapping result.

Comment: Yes this is happening in the success block, It's getting the property directly from the mapping result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can use any method on the returned proxy object other than `description`. That means not supplying it as a variable to `NSLog`.

The true objects will be stored into the data store. Depending on what you need to do you may want to go and retrieve them directly (by fetching or using the managed object id).

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the advice. I seen mutableCopy mentioned in the [docs](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/RestKit/0.20.0/Classes/RKMappingSourceObject.html) so I tried it and it worked [feature.featureType mutableCopy]; Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about RestKit, but it seems that the 4 calls to `featureMapping` are each inserting a new `RKAttributeMapping` - that does not seem to make any sense. Maybe this is the reason you have a problem with your `featureType` property.

Comment: Hi, I've just tested with one featureMapping call but the problem persists. The reason I have modeled the data this way is that I need to store it in core data. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I don't think re-creating the featureMapping over and over again is correct. If it is, it would be quite bad design IMO.